# Finding convergence using Limit Comparison Test

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What should I set as my second function to determine the convergence of
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln(n)} {\mathbb e^n\sqrt n} $$

by the limit comparison test? I'm not too sure where to begin, any help is appreciated.

Comment: $ln(n) < \sqrt n$ for $n$ large enough.

Answer (score 0):

From this plot using Wolfram Alpha, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20ln(n)%2F(sqrt(n)*exp(n)),%201%2Fn%5E2%20from%20n%3D1%20to%20100), it can be said that,

$$\frac{ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}e^n} \leq \frac{1}{n^2} \forall n \in [1,\infty)$$

Hence using the limit comparison test it can be said that,

$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{ln(n)} {(\sqrt[2]n)e^n} $ is convergent because,
$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1} {n^2} $ is convergent.

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n/b_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ln(n)/\sqrt{n}e^n}{1/n^2}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ln(n)n^{3/2}}{e^n}$$
Since the above limit is in the $\infty/\infty$ form, we differentiate using the L'Hospital Rule.
$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{3}{2}n^{1/2}ln(n) + n^{1/2}}{e^n}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{3}{4}n^{-1/2}ln(n) + \frac{3}{2}n^{-1/2}ln(n) + \frac{1}{2}n^{-1/2}}{e^n}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{9}{4}n^{-1/2}ln(n)}{e^n}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{9}{4}ln(n)}{\sqrt{n}e^n}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{9}{4n}}{\sqrt{n}e^n + e^n(\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}})}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\frac{9.2\sqrt{n}}{4n}}{e^n(2n+1)}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{18\sqrt{n}}{e^n(8n^2+4n)}$$
$$\implies \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{9/\sqrt{n}}{e^n(16n+4) + e^n(8n^2+4n)} = 0$$

Comment: You just used the inequality comparison test, but no the limit comparison test. It would be easier to have in mind that $\dfrac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n} e^n}=\dfrac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \dfrac{1}{e^n}\leq \dfrac{1}{e^n}$.

Comment: @user27454 : The comparison test that I have used is the same as the limit comparison test that has been asked in the question, you can check the definition here : http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/SeriesCompTest.aspx;

Comment: @rotaiva No, the limit comparison test would involve finding a sequence $b_n$ such that the $lim_{n->\infty} \frac{a_n}{b_n} = 0$

Comment: @rotaiva I didn't see any link in the question, so I assumed I was confused and your answer is enough. However, do you see a text in blue with the title "Limit Comparison Test" in your link? That's the one that I thought dubbler26 wanted to use

Comment: Once you have the inequality comparison test, you can use the limit comparison test by setting $b_n = {1 \over {e^n}}$.  The limit of $a_n\over b_n$ will be a constant.

Comment: @browngreen the limit that you describe is actually $0$, and in that case you cannot apply the "Limit Comparison Test". For instance, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1/n^2}{1/n}=0$ but it is not true that $a_n=1/n$ and $b_n=1/n^2$ both converge or both diverge.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\frac{\ln n}{e^n\sqrt n} \le \frac {\sqrt n}{ e^n\sqrt n} = \frac 1 {e^n},
$$
so the series converges.